# How to achieve pushbutton type effect using bitmaps

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++-6

Hello there I have a issue related to the usage of the bitmap enabled Dialog window.I have created a keyboard type layout and i wish to get the input through keyboard also.When i use the mouse I am able to get the button(s) pressed and also all the buttons are working fine - the other images `DEFAULT,SELECTED,DISABLED` ..all get loaded and work since I am using the function here `m_BtnBtn1Ctrl.LoadBitmaps` ,But then any key pressed on keyboard and the corresponding character on the screen isn't able to do the same as I have been able to do it with clicking of the mouse(and using the `Loadbitmaps()` function ).

I am using these 3 functions to achieve the same action and effect as that using a mouse
LoadBitmap()
SetBitmap()
Invalidate()

I also tried this piece of code

```
HBITMAP hbm = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "\\res\\Selected\\bitmap21.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

and

```
bitmap.Attach((HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "\\res\\Selected\\bitmap21.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));
```

but these don't seem to give the pressed button effect though internally they work.Can some one please help me with this

Thanks and regards
Sayonee

Collapse

```
BOOL KeyBoard_press::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    CString strTemp;
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if ( pMsg->wParam == 0x41 || pMsg->wParam == 0x61) //check for both 'a' and 'A'
            OnBtnBtn1();
        if (pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN || pMsg->wParam == VK_DELETE ||
            pMsg->wParam == VK_ESCAPE || pMsg->wParam == VK_TAB ||
            pMsg->wParam == VK_UP || pMsg->wParam == VK_DOWN || GetKeyState (VK_CONTROL))
            {
                ::TranslateMessage (pMsg);
                ::DispatchMessage (pMsg);
                return TRUE;                // DO NOT process further
            }
    }
    return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Comment: hello Kerido thanks a ton for the reply on how to simulate the virtual keyboard...sorry for replying this late bcoz i thought i wont be able to get any reply/help regarding this question...

Comment: but i am still stuck when it comes to processing the WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP messages these are the messages which are to processed since without first clicking on the virtual keyboard i am not able to get the pushdown effect on the virtual keyboard..

Comment: and moreover when i click with a mouse as a normal user would the pushbutton comes naturally but when i press the particular key again it doesnt give a pushbutton effect instead it remains UP and the border line appears as if its been selected.....I am stuck here can you please let me know how to proceed further and to be frank I am a newbie in VC++...thanks again for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have a series of buttons that simulate a computer keyboard layout. whenever the user presses a key on the keyboard, you need to simulate a button click in your dialog box. You have provided bitmaps for each state of each button.

To do this, I would process the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages. In the handlers, use some mapping of the key to the actual button instance. Then, send the `BM_SETSTATE` to the button control.

Then, process the `WM_COMMAND` message from each of the buttons and check for the `BN_CLICKED` code.

Comment: hello Kerido thanks a ton but i am not able to get the pushdown effect on the virtual keyboard..and moreover when i click with a mouse as a normal user would the pushbutton comes naturally but when i press the "same" key again it doesnt give a pushbutton effect instead it remains UP and the border line appears as if its been selected.....I am stuck here can you please let me know how to proceed further and to be frank I am a newbie in VC++...thanks again for all the help

Comment: Hi Kerido sorry for replying late and i had emailed to you in detail about the issue I have ...i am able to get the pushbutton effect on pressing any letter such as the key A..but now immediately if I click the button with bitmap A and again if I press the key A on the keyboard there is no pushbutton effect ...any suggestions please do let me know ..thanks again

Comment: @Keridohello Kerido thanks a ton for the reply on how to simulate the virtual keyboard...sorry for replying this late bcoz i thought i wont be able to get any reply/help regarding this question...but i am still stuck when it comes to processing the WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP messages these are the messages which are to processed since without first clicking on the virtual keyboard

Comment: i am not able to get the pushdown effect on the virtual keyboard..and moreover when i click with a mouse as a normal user would the pushbutton comes naturally but when i press the particular key again it doesnt give a pushbutton effect instead it remains UP and the border line appears as if its been selected.....I am stuck here can you please let me know how to proceed further and to be frank I am a newbie in VC++...thanks again for all the help